# How to change default launcher activity with firebase notification when app in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

when app in background in Firebase and there is notification without data just notification title and text
 Is there a way to determine which activity will be opened and change the app launcher activity that open by default

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
    val resultIntent = Intent(this, PrivateChatWithListView::class.java)
   // Create the TaskStackBuilder
    val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
        // Add the intent, which inflates the back stack
        resultIntent.putExtra("senderName" , senderName)
        addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent)
        // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

Comment: OnMessageReceived will be called only on foregournd or background in case if there is data